# Change property of a button programmatically

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton

I am working on another person's code. He has created some UIButtons in a UIView in the interface builder(not programmatically). 
But now the UI has changed slightly. When the view loads, based on some conditions, some buttons have to be disabled/enabled. I am a bit confused about, whether to alter the code by creating buttons dynamically and disable the buttons based on conditions, or is there any other way like referring the button by tag and changing its property. Sounds like a silly question, I am still working on improving my basic skills in Iphone app development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an `IBOutlet` to the `UIButton`, then you can do things like:

```
myButton.enabled = NO; // or YES
myButton.hidden = NO; // or YES
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create an IBOutlet using interface building which will give you a reference to the button in your nib file. From there you can modify the parameters on the button which was loaded.